# Infinite scroll repeate same id again from database

Tags: php, jquery

friends i am trying to load data on scroll using php and jquery. my problem is database is loading from last id but last loaded id's are repeating. i am unable to find weather its because of jquery conflict or my code error. i am using jquery 1.11.1 version. please see the below image for better understanding.

[image]

and my jquery to get data from php is

```
 $(window).scroll(function(){
    if  ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
       loadData();
    }
  });

function loadData() 
{ 
    $('div.postloader').html('<img src="http://www.zesteve.com/img/loader.gif">');
    $.post("/getData.php?lastID=" + $(".post-list:last").attr("id"),     
    function(data){
        if (data != "") {
        $(".post-list:last").after(data);            
        }
       $('div.postloader').empty();
    });

};
```

and in getData.php i am using

```
$last_id  = $_GET['lastID'];
  $stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM review WHERE id < :lastID AND user_id = :user_id order by id DESC LIMIT 5');
  $stmt->execute(array(':lastID' => $last_id,':user_id'=>$user_id));
```

friends if you not understand anything here please comment. please help me where i am doing wrong?

Comment: You're appending elements with `id` attribute, not `data-id`, so either replace the `id` with `data-id` or get the last id using `$(".post-list:last").attr("id")`

Comment: eitan sorry its id only not data-id i corrected in the example

Comment: I think it might use id 93 (as last id) because it is the last one created without JS. How about if you try `.find("post-list:last").attr("id"),`

Comment: its not the problem with the last id i am getting last id as 93 its in DESC order so it should be 92, 91, 90, 89 ,88. i want to know why its repeating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're pulling the data from the server too fast, try adding a flag that will prevent pulling the items while the request is running:

```
var flagPulling = false;
function loadData() { 
    if( flagPulling ) {
        return;
    }
    flagPulling = true;
    $('div.postloader').html('<img src="http://www.zesteve.com/img/loader.gif">');
    $.post("/getData.php?lastID=" + $(".post-list:last").attr("id"), function(data){
        if (data != "") {
            $(".post-list:last").after(data);            
        }
       $('div.postloader').empty();
       flagPulling = false;
    });
};
```

Comment: what did you edited second time? any corrections made

Comment: when i load page its asked me load again answer is edited

Comment: No, I didn't editted anything, open this question in a different tab and you'll see the latest version of my answer

Comment: since 5 hrs i am braking my head and changing the code again and again. changing jquery version to lower, but no use. your awesome its working grate. i never understand jquery. thank you very much

Comment: so flagPulling is a speed braker

Comment: Yes, because `$.post` is ansync, so you need to make sure that you won't run the code until you get a response back from the server

Answer (score 0):

Compare the following:

```
$last_id  = $_GET['lastID'];
```

to

```
$.post("/getData.php?lastID=" + $(".post-list:last").attr("id"), function(data){
```

You're using POST but looking for `lastID` in `$_GET`.

Try changing to

```
$last_id  = $_POST['lastID'];
```

Comment: Because the user is passing the parameter in the query string, it is also available in `$_GET['lastID']`